# Genymotion:Dark Blank screen with "Free for personal use"

Tags: genymotion

I have installed Genymotion successfully and everything seems to be ok, but when I run every single default application such as browser or  phone or etc. I face with a black blank screen 
with just this sentence "*Free for personal use*"

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

1. reboot
2. clear cache
3. Install Virual box Extensin
4. Use BRIDGE for network, not a NAT
5. Check video drivers
6. Use  VMXSVGA not VGA!